# Single medical term for "taking a pulse"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, technical, medical, scientific-language

I have been searching for a technical/medical term to use in place of "taking a pulse". I see some texts use "palpatory measurements" in place of the colloquial "taking a pulse" but I want to use a single word. Perhaps "Palpatometry" could be used but there is no dictionary entry for this term. Any suggestions, esp. scientific/medical terms?

-RD

Comment: Pulse measurement: https://www.uofmhealth.org/health-library/hw233473

Comment: There's a noun *palpation*,  examining by touch, but it's not specific to pulse measurement.

Comment: It is one of the typical 4 measurements included in "taking vital signs" which can be summarized as "vitals"

Comment: So, the root *sphygm-* means pulse. You could adopt *sphygmopalpation* as your single word.

Comment: @jack-oflaherty Thanks, 'sphygmopalpation' is good but it does not indicate 'measurement'. Perhaps "sphygmopalpatiometry"? But it is not a dictionary word.

Comment: Why do you feel that "take [the patient's] pulse" is unacceptably colloquial or is not technical? If you go to far into inventing or reverse-engineering terms you may end up with something comprehensible only to yourself. Perhaps the issue is that technical literature is more likely to talk about the results than the procedure: "The patient's pulse was ___..."

Comment: I am writing a technical paper and want to use a more technical term.

Comment: If you are referring to multiple measurements, you could say that the pulse (or heart rate) was *monitored*, but for a single instance I think *take* the pulse is correct, just as you *take* or (record) temperature.

Comment: There may be more than rate involved - there are also strength and regularity. If it's for a paper to be published, the best bet is to stick with what others have done.